# Microscopic image

Tags: crystal-structure

When I was reading a chapter on solids structure then i thought of how the real structure would be like if seen from microscope.
Hence I want the real microscopic molecular image of NaCl(common salt) and glass
I searched on Google but I don't get the real image

Comment: You might look for atomic force microscopy. Do not expect kind of photographs as the technique does not work with light. But the imagery one gets is as close as possible to microscopy picture such as those using visible light or electrons beams. There is a lot of physics behind your Q. Basically at the atomic scale no wavelength can "see". Tough x rays diffraction can also give images of lattices, but those despite based on optics, are even more far from a commonly intended picture of objects.

Comment: https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/dislocations/observing.php has a nice overview...

Comment: And here is an image with AFM: https://dqmp.unige.ch/renner/2013/11/04/atomic-force-micrograph-of-nacl/

Comment: [Google image](https://www.google.com/search?q=microscopic+image+of+sodium+chloride&sxsrf=ALeKk02ImM5KY1s7bfyT6plUJL6j0ENZ-g:1592489064029&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC_uCHxIvqAhXOTX0KHaH2DWoQ_AUoAXoECAsQAw&biw=1366&bih=657)

Comment: There are no molecules in solid NaCl. What you are asking about only exists in gas phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An optical microscope can magnify the crystals of sodium chloride so you can see their beautiful symmetry:

[image]

But you said you want to get down to molecular (atomic) size. At those distances, we generate images with data (positions and bond distances) obtained from x-ray crystallography:

[image]

This picture suggests what a tiny crystal of sodium chloride would look like if you could see the individual ions. The colors are not real; these ions are smaller than the wavelength of visible light. But it is interesting that the maker of the picture colored the chlorine ions green.

That picture is the way I think of the crystal stacked: the ions are touching, but then I can only see the surface of the crystal. If I had x-ray vision and could see into the crystal, it might look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Not really like that. You'll get its diffraction reflected picture.